# Python re.sub: replace part of matching string that contains an arbitrary number of capturing groups

Tags: python, regex

I know that there are other questions which deal with the problem of replacing only part of a matching string using re.sub, but the answers revolve around referring back to capturing groups. My situation is a bit different:

I'm generating regexes like `'(?:i|æ|ʏ|ɞ).(?:i|æ|ʏ|ɞ)'` and `^.` in another part of the application. If I have the string `'abcd'`, and the pair `('b', 'c')`, I want to replace all instances of `b` where the regex matches at the period character (`.`).

For example, if I have the rule `'(?:x|y|z).(?:h|i|j)'`, and the desired change is `a` to `b`, the following should occur:

```
xah -> xbh
yai -> ybi
zaz -> zaz (no change)
```

I've tried using `re.sub`, replacing the `.` with my target in the search string and with my replacement in the replacement string, but this replaces the whole match in the target string, when in reality I only want to change a small part. My problem with using match groups and referring back to them in the replacement is that I don't know how many there will be, or what order they'll be in - there might not even be any - so I'm trying to find a flexible solution.

Any help is very appreciated! It's quite difficult to explain, so if further clarification is needed please ask :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "lookahead" and "lookbehind" assertions, like so:

```
import re

tests = (
    ('xah', 'xbh'),
    ('yai', 'ybi'),
    ('zaz', 'zaz'),
)

for test_in, test_out in tests:
    out = re.sub('(?<=x|y|z)a(?=h|i|j)', 'b', test_in)
    assert test_out == out
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'd already considered the lookahead idea, and it works perfectly for two groups. However, I couldn't get it to work when the regex contains more than two capture groups, like `'(a|b|c)(d|e|f)a(g|h|i)'`.

Comment: @CadelWatson - In that case, try `re.sub('(?<=(?:a|b|c)(?:d|e|f))a(?=g|h|i)', 'b', 'adag')`

Comment: Ahah, that's it! Thanks for the help.